# Detect changes in time series

Tags: time-series, change-point

I came across a picture of an application prototype that finds significant changes ("trends" - not spikes/outliers) in traffic data:

[image]

I want to write a program (Java, optionally R) that is able to do the same - but because my statistic skills are a little rusty, I need to dig into this topic again.

*What approach/algorithm should I use/research therefore?*

Comment: This is similar to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/finding-the-change-point-in-data-from-a-piecewise-linear-function

Comment: Yes, and the answers will be the same, too.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways that "a structural break" may occur.

If there is a change in the Intercept or a change in Trend in "the latter portion of the time series" then one would be better suited to perform Intervention Detection (N.B. this is the empirical identification of the significant impact of an unspecified Deterministic Variable such as a Level Shift or a Change in Trend or the onset of a Seasonal Pulse ). Intervention Detection then is a pre-cursor to Intervention Modelling where a suggested variable is included in the model. You can find information on the web by googling "AUTOMATIC INTERVENTION DETECTION" . Some authors use the term "OUTLIER DETECTION" but like a lot of statistical language this can be confusing/imprecise . Detected Interventions can be any of the following (detecting a significant change in the mean of the residuals );

a 1 period change in Level ( i.e. a Pulse )
a multi-period contiguous change in Level ( i.e. a change in Intercept )
a systematic Pulse ( i.e. a Seasonal Pulse )
a trend change (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13,15 ..... )
These procedures are easily programmed IN R/SAS/Matlab and routinely available in a number of commercially available time series packages however there are many pitfalls that you need to be wary of such as whether to detect the stochastic structure first or do Intervention detection on the original series. This is like the chicken and egg problem. Early work in this area was limited to type 1's and as such will probably be insufficient for your needs as your examples illustrate LEVEL SHIFTS.

There is a lot of material on the web and even a free program at http://www.autobox.com/30day.exe that even allows you to use your own data for 30days. You might learn lot "by simply watching" as Yogi once said and replicate their results.

The web references for the exact equations for you to use can be found starting at page 134 in 
http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/autoboxusersguide.pdf . I am one of the authors of AUTOBOX.

Comment: @stefanos: Can you please tell me the name of the application as I am always interested in pursuing software solutions dealing with this issue. You can email me at my contact info.

Answer (score 3):

In R, many packages are potentially useful, as partially summarized in the CRAN Task View on time series:https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html. Here is a relevant excerpt on change detection:

> Change point detection is provided in strucchange and strucchangeRcpp
> (using linear regression models) and in trend (using nonparametric
> tests). The changepoint package provides many popular changepoint
> methods, and ecp does nonparametric changepoint detection for
> univariate and multivariate series. changepoint.np implements the
> nonparametric PELT algorithm, changepoint.mv detects changepoints in
> multivariate time series, while changepoint.geo implements the
> high-dimensional changepoint detection method GeomCP. Factor-augmented
> VAR (FAVAR) models are estimated by a Bayesian method with FAVAR.
> InspectChangepoint uses sparse projection to estimate changepoints in
> high-dimensional time series. Rbeast provides Bayesian change-point
> detection and time series decomposition. breakfast includes methods
> for fast multiple change-point detection and estimation.

For those interested in Bayesian methods, three possibilities are `Rbeast`, `bcp`, and `mcp` ( I am sure that there are more than three of them). Below is a quick example using the Rbeast package developed by myself (https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast):

```
libray(Rbeast)
out = beast(Nile) # the annual streamflow data for the Nile River
plot(out)
```

The `Pr(tcp)` subplot shows the probability of sudden/significant changes over time, with the peaks given the most likely locations of changepoint occurrence. In this example, only one was detected. The `SlpSgn` subplot shows the probability of slopes being positive (the upper red portion), being zero (the middle green portion), and being negative (the lower blue portion).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try cpm or changepoint package in R. It is free to use.  Also research change point model or sequential change detection.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Cherese. At present, this is more of a comment than an answer. Would you mind elaborating on this a little?